# Django - Runtime database switching

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-middleware, django-managers

In my work we want to run a server with multiple databases. The databases switching should occur when you acces a url like `http://myapp.webpage.com` or `http://other.webpage.com`. We want to run only one server instance and at the moment of the HTTP request switch the database and return the corresponding response.

We've been looking for a mantainable and 'Django-friendly' solution. In our investigation we have found possible ways to do this, but we have not enough information about.

## Option 1: Django middleware

The django middleware runs each time the server receive a HTTP request.

1. Making a database switch here could be the best option but using [django database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/) as far as I know only allow to change the database for a model or group or models.
2. Another option is to set a [django model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance) instance in the middleware and force all models to re-assign the `objects` attribute from an added attribute in the custom middleware.
3. My last option is to create a new attribute in the request object received by the middleware that return the `database alias` from `settings.py` and in each model query use the [using method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset).

## Option 2: Class-based View Mixin

Create a mixin that use the past three options, but I **the mixin must be set in ALL the Class-based views**. If a programmer forget to set the mixin and it comes to a production server, the data could be (or stop being) in the right database, and I don't wanna take the risk.

## Option 3: Changing the database settings in runtime

This option works but [Is not recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime) and is too risky.

## UPDATE:

### How this works?

**middlewares.py**

```
import django.conf as conf
import os.path


class SelectDB(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        print request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
        file_database = open("booklog/database.txt", "r")
        database = file_database.read(10)
        file_database.close()
        if database != 'default':
            conf.settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = database
```

Any information that help us to solve will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this the whole reason database routers exist? What disadvantage do you perceive to that solution?

Comment: Please correct me if im wrong but, as I far I remember the database routers only work for some models that you define, not the whole database

Comment: hmmm, perhaps a dumb question, but how robust will this be to user #1 being in myapp's db and user #2 simultaneously being in other's db?  that would kinda preclude option #3 regardless of risk or not, no?

Comment: No, it works on the whole DB. I use this to fall back to a backup database if access to the primary becomes slow. It works transparently.

Comment: @ire_and_curses I know this is dumb, but, could you teach me a chunk of code? If I generate the model router how can I catch the request object in order to obtain the url? Can I know when a model router is run? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

## Answer (it worked for me)

The question was already answered [here, in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27422908/3541922). I'd love this functionality were in django. It was a bit hard to find the way to make this possible.

I think that is important to comment the great work that [Wilduck](https://github.com/Wilduck) made with the django plugin [django-dynamic-db-router](https://github.com/ambitioninc/django-dynamic-db-router), it's a great plugin that makes possible this operation in (a bit) different way.

Thanks a lot to @JL Peyret and @ire_and_curses.

And as an answer to @ire_and_curses. At least in this moment, in the project I'm working it's what we need. In previous projects we needed a similar behavior and made one server per instance was terrible to mantain and update each server, even automating the process.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your solution.