# is django db able to have a secondary db set as back up? django

Tags: python, django, database, replication

What I am trying to say is, I have two database and they are replicates.  Is it possible for django to have settings that if first (primary db) is down / cannot be connected then connect to the second one until the first one is back up?

I believe this can be done in server side, but I am wondering if it can be done with django easily instead of touching the db servers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401779/dynamically-set-database-based-on-request-in-django/27422908#27422908 check this

Comment: not sure, but just a suggestion for every request check database connected or not , if timeout comes just change the connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Multiple Databases Fallback to Master if Slave is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608906/django-multiple-databases-fallback-to-master-if-slave-is-down)

Comment: @Shiva to my understanding with the other forums, I have to make a middleware then add it into my middleware section?

Comment: @ZaytsevDmitry great, that post did help a lot

Comment: @Shiva thx for that url, but Zaytsev's is more closer to what I needed

Comment: @Tsuna I believe I got it working and it's not middleware that is needed, only need to add extra variable for settings.py